# Which of these is a repository pattern?

Tags: c#, repository, design-patterns

My domain entities are lined up like a tree:

Root
- Child 1
-- Child 1.1
-- Child 1.2
- Child 2
-- Child 2.1
-- Child 2.2

We ended up with 2 (rather strong) opinions on how a repository should be designed around these domain objects:

Opinion 1:
I need 2 repositories Child1Repository & Child2Repository which gets managed by a RootFacade/RootManager class to call the appropriate method on the repository. The 2 child repositories handle only the DAL operations while the RootFacade is the BLL. The RootFacade exposes DTO's to the application while internally all the 3 repositories use domain objects

Opinion 2:
I need 1 repository RootRepository which handles everything (BLL + DAL). The repository exposes DTO's while internally it works with the domain objects

I would like to have some perspective on these 2 points & which is really the way to go about for a repository implementation.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Just to be clear - is this a physical inheritance, like a manager and subordinates, or a class inheritance with the children being derived types?

Comment: The root is a container for various child elements. There is no physical inheritance between the root - child elements but there is a tree inheritance to all the child elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes shouldn't take on more responsibility than they need to, and it definitely sounds like the approach of a `RootRepository` is the wrong way to go here. It absorbs too much complexity and is responsible for too many entities. Of the two options you presented, the first is the better choice: have more repositories that are each responsible for their own corner of your domain.

However, that said, it's not clear to me why you have a `RootManager` at all. I would much rather have a series of `DomainObjectRepositories` which each managed their own business logic internally, and only exposed the relevant public operations, then defer actual database operations to a data-access object `DomainObjectDao`. Having an omniscient all-the-biz-logic class is a monstrous code smell, and smacks of enterprisey overkill in this particular case.

Comment: A Child type cannot exist without the Root. While there is no physical inheritance between the root - child combination, a Root is a container for various collections of child items. The child items can be a tree collection. 

So, even if I have various ChildRepository implementation, it always needs the Root context to be able to do any operation. Besides the business rules are defined at the root level & so the question will be will I need to call across repositories to validate my rules (& so will need the RootFacade/Manager class)

Comment: Ah, I see; that wasn't clear from your original question. However, I still think my answer stands: a `Book` can't exist without a `Library` to put it in, yet there may still be operations you want to do on `Books` that have nothing to do with `Libraries` (for example, finding a book across any library in town and not just a specific library's collection).

As far as calling across multiple repositories, that's okay if the two repositories already have some kind of affiliation with each other. There's nothing inherently wrong with one repository asking another one a question.

Comment: I like your example of library-books since it is how my entities are lined up. 

The key difference in my case is that all operations are on the library like: library.AddBook(), library.IssueBook() etc. The book cannot have its own operations in my case

There are no multiple library scenarios.

Comment: If that's truly the case, then I'd agree that your specific case doesn't require a BookRepository to expose itself. But it still looks wrong to me to have that many objects managed by one omniscient entity. I would have a tough time believing that this was the optimal way to design things (without knowing more about your specific situation, of course).

Answer (score 0):

We work with option 1 and it fits well for us. Say child 1 is a userRepository and child 2 is a role repositorywith the facade being the security facade. The user repository would return a user domain object that was the aggregate root and the user objects contains roles. We would only really be using the role repository for GetAllRoles.

Our domain objects have a GetDTO method that returns the dtos for transport by the facade.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So, in this case, the UserRepository will handle rules like: If a user is in role "a", he cannot be assigned role "b"

The RoleRepository performs only DAL operations

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No that is the responsibility of you domain object to handle the business logic.

Look into the specification pattern for somethign like this. No repository should contain any business logic.